# Why does scope chain goes to Global context?

Tags: javascript

I have been fiddling around with some piece of Javascript and I find console logs 1 for below code, However I was expecting 2, as it is 'a' which created b.

```
function b(){      
   c();
    function c(){            
        d();
        function d(){
             console.log(myVar);
        }
    }
}
function a(){
    var myVar=2;

    b();
}
var myVar=1;

a();
```

But again I see b sits in lexical environment of window so it is getting the value from there. So how does scope chain work?Does it take value from caller/ creator or lexical scope?

Comment: The scope chain will be created during the time when JS engine interprets the code.

Comment: `a` did not "create" `b`. It just called it. The scope is determined by where the function is defined, not where it's called.

Comment: I can see how this particular example might be confusing with regards to the value that `myVar` takes on, but technically you actually have **2** `myVar`s. the `myVar` in function a is actually a redeclaration, assigning an inner `myVar` to 2 which does not affect the outer one. Had function a set `myVar` like `myVar = 2`, then the global one would have been overridden and the log printed "2".

https://jsbin.com/jojaguwoku/edit?js,console

Comment: @PerryMitchell: Yeah it was redclaration which was confusing ! Now I got it ! Thanks for your insight and jsbin !